# If I sleep in a Magic Bedroll while benefiting from the Healthful Rest and Summon Elysian Thrush spells, how many HP do I regain?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, healing, hit-points

Each of these increase the number of HP you get back during a rest.

The Healthful Rest spell description (SC, p. 11) says:

> Each affected creature regains twice the hit points and ability damage it otherwise would have regained during that day, depending on its activity level

The Summon Elysian Thrush spell description (SC, p. 214) says:

> Those within 30 feet who listen to the thrush's song while resting recover at twice the normal natural healing rate.

The description of the Magic Bedroll (MIC, p. 163) says:

> After sleeping for 8 hours in the bedroll, you recover 1 hit point per character level, in addition to the hit points you recover normally.

If I sleep 8 hours in a Magic Bedroll while listening to an Elysian Thrush, and under the effect of Healthful Rest, how many HP do I regain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A creature that's the subject of the 1st-level Clr spell ***healthful rest*** [conj] (*Spell Compendium* 111) and that sleeps 8 hours in a ***magic bedroll*** (*Magic Item Compendium* 163–4) (500 gp; 6 lbs.) sees its natural healing rate multiplied by 3.

A creature that's the subject of the spell *healthful rest* and that listens continuously while resting to the song of an **Elysian thrush** (*Planar Handbook* 118) also sees its natural healing rate multiplied by 3.

A typical creature can't benefit from all three effects at once because a creature must specifically *sleep* in the *magic bedroll* and must specifically *listen* to the thrush's song. A sleeping creature still makes [Listen](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#listen) skill checks at a −10 penalty, but success on such a Listen skill check awakens the creature, spoiling the benefits the *magic bedroll* would otherwise provide.

Each of these sources is a *different* source therefore they should combine for cumulative effect (see [Stack](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_stack&alpha=S) on *Player's Handbook* 313), but the [nonstandard multiplication rules](http://dndsrd.net/basics.html#multiplying) apply because hp regained from natural healing isn't a real-world value.

Note that, depending on the DM's reading, natural healing can be increased even more by, for example, a lizardfolk that takes the feat Reptilian Healing (*Dragon* #335 57), a feline that takes the feat [Healing *Chi*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fools/20030401c) (Web article "April Fools: Fabulous Cats!"), and by anyone that takes the feats Bloodthirsty (*Dragon* #311 45), Faster Healing (*Complete Warrior* 98) or Hibernate (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 100).